# Error when checking input: expected lstm_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 23, 1, 16)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I've been running into this error and I am quite unsure how to solve it. I know that my input is expecting 3 dimensions, but I have a shape of 4. Can someone guide me how I can narrow it down? I've read post where there are 3 dimensions, and array shapes less than 3 or so.. But I haven't seen a solution on overflow with a bigger shape and dimension...

```
def generator(batch_size,from_list_x,from_list_y):

    assert len(from_list_x) == len(from_list_y)
    total_size = len(from_list_x)

    while True: #keras generators should be infinite

        for i in range(0,total_size,batch_size):
            yield np.array(from_list_x[i:i+batch_size]), np.array(from_list_y[i:i+batch_size])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,16),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

    # fit network
pyplot.figure(figsize=(16, 25))
# for i in range(len(train)):
history = model.fit_generator(generator(8, train_X, train_Y), epochs=20, steps_per_epoch = 7, verbose=0, shuffle=True)
print('loss ', str(i), history.history['loss'][len(history.history['loss'])-1],'\n')
```

I am getting an error with this line :

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator(8, train_X, train_Y), epochs=20, steps_per_epoch = 7, verbose=0, shuffle=True)
```

Traceback:

ValueError

```
        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-17bb96b50588> in <module>()
      2 pyplot.figure(figsize=(16, 25))
      3 # for i in range(len(train)):
----> 4 history = model.fit_generator(generator(8, train_X, train_Y), epochs=20, steps_per_epoch = 7, verbose=0, shuffle=True)
      5 
      6 #     plot history

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dh\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dh\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1424             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1425             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1426             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1427 
   1428     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dh\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    189                 outs = model.train_on_batch(x, y,
    190                                             sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 191                                             class_weight=class_weight)
    192 
    193                 if not isinstance(outs, list):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dh\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1212             x, y,
   1213             sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1214             class_weight=class_weight)
   1215         if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
   1216             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dh\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    752             feed_input_shapes,
    753             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 754             exception_prefix='input')
    755 
    756         if y is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dh\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    124                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    125                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 126                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    127                 if not check_batch_axis:
    128                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 23, 1, 16)

<Figure size 1152x1800 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: Of course that's where the error is. That's where you call your function. What's the actual error? Post a traceback

Comment: @MadPhysicist Error when checking input: expected lstm_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 23, 1, 16)

Comment: That's not a traceback. Please edit your question with the full stack trace.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i edited it, sorry bout that. let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: try np.squeeze. if I had to guess, you have a reduction operation that's preserving the reduced dimension.

Comment: What are the training arrays? Give a sample if you can. At least provide the shape. It's hard to reproduce the error without full information.

Comment: But at the same time, thanks for being responsive. It's refreshing to see someone that accepts the fact that they're new to this and fixes what's asked instead of getting defensive.

Comment: Sorry I was trying other things and didn't have stackoverflow opened. I read somewhere that .shape can help my problem, and used it to display the shape. I just played around with the code and got it to work. Thanks for your help though! haha im new to python, it's only my 5th day working with it. So i don't think i have any room to get defensive, especially if i am getting help.

Comment: If you fixed your code, I'd recommend deleting your question. You have a good attitude and you'll learn fast. Good luck!